# adding ng-repeat is causing Error: $compile:ctreq

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-leaflet-directive

I have a custom directive that requires the leaflet directive so I can access the controller:

```
restrict: 'E',
require: '^leaflet',
scope: {

},
template: "",
link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {

}
```

When I use my custom directive in my app's controller without implementing `ng-repeat` it works fine. Like this:

**controller's HTML without `ng-repeat`**

```
<leaflet defaults="defaults" center="center" markers="markers" layers="layers" paths="paths">
  <ng-include src="/markers.html" />
  <my-directive 
    waypoints="wps">
  </my-directive>
</leaflet>
```

**controller's JS without `ng-repeat`**

```
$scope.wps = [[32.745,-117.2776],[32.693,-117.3188]];
```

However, when I try to add `ng-repeat` I end up getting the following error:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.12/$compile/ctreq?p0=leaflet&p1=myDirective
```

**controller's HTML with `ng-repeat`**

```
    <leaflet defaults="defaults" center="center" markers="markers" layers="layers" paths="paths">
        <ng-include src="/markers.html" />
        <my-directive 
            ng-repeat="(name, data) in routes"
            name="{{ name }}"
            waypoints="data.wps">
        </my-directive>
    </leaflet>
```

**controller's JS with `ng-repeat`**

```
$scope.routes = {
  r1: {
    wps: [[32.745,-117.2776],[32.693,-117.3188]]
  }
}
```

What have I screwed up?

Comment: I assume it's because ng-repeat creates a new scope. You need to pass your leaflet object as a parameter

Comment: When you use `ng-repeat` a new scope is created for each row, and since your child directive creates isolated scope the parent hierarchy gets gets affect. Since you child does a `require` on parent directive controller, this issue may be coming.

Comment: @aorfevre what do you mean pass the leaflet object as a parameter? Where would I do that?

Comment: I'm pretty confident the error lies in the code you don't show. There's no reason this shouldn't work.

Comment: There is one line I was removing in my code. I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `<ng-include src="/markers.html" />` before your directive. You need to explicitly close that tag. See [this bug report](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11475).